# Azure Logic Apps: Error "When a work item is created" Visual Studio

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to create a Logic App that triggers when a work item is created in Visual Studio Online.

I've used the `When a work item is created` Visual Studio trigger and configured it with my Visual Studio online account.

When the Logic App runs, it does find a work item that meets the criteria but then immediately fails with:

Status code: 404

Body

```
{ 
  "status": 404, 
  "message": "The work item 4660 does not exist at time 8/16/2017 6:35:45 PM.
              clientRequestId: 46c0afee-ec24-4593-bc19-9d3979b2c0f5",
  "source": "vsts-logic-cp-northcentralus.logic-ase-northcentralus.p.azurewebsites.net" 
 }
```

The work item ID in the error message matches the ID of the work item I created that meets the criteria specified in the activity. So it did find at first, since that's how the activity got triggered to begin with. But then it fails with this cryptic 404 and I've got not clue why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This turned out to be a bug in the Azure Logic Apps Visual Studio connector** as acknowledged by Microsoft's Logic Apps team.

It has since been addressed and I am no longer seeing this issue.